# Can you build a symbol table from a VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, tooling-api

Is there a parser for a VF page that will build a symbol table?  I'd like to know what external references exist so I can tell what public variables and methods are unused in a project.  Looks like the Tooling API has nothing along these lines.

Thanks

Comment: I'm writing a tool like that, but the way I'm going, I'll be at least six months before I could even possibly release it.

Comment: This seems duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33903/how-can-i-find-unused-methods-and-variables

Comment: The Force.com IDE is now open source so eventually a local model of the Apex and Visualsource may get done. Right now the work is left to the server so the local model is just a place keeper - [ApexPageModel](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/7027fab86b53ccbc4cbe69b9954c5f1e8bc2432f/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/internal/components/apex/page/ApexPageModel.java).