# How to differentiate between ApexClassorTrigger name and ApexTestClass name?

Tags: apex, unit-test, tooling-api

I have extracted all the component from Salesforce Org so I want the names of all the TestClasses which covers all ApexClasses.
    I have created excel sheet such as Component Type, Component Name and I want to add 1 more column IsTestClass.
    IstestClass contain Yes or No. If Yes means component name should be ApexTest class or else No

I have all the ApexClass names, but I want only the apex test class name.

Comment: use naming conventions in your org, so that all test classes are next to each other? For example `TEST_myClass1` and `TEST_myVFController1`. Like this all your TC will be next to each other

Comment: Good suggestion by Novarg. @Amit, I am afraid that there is any direct way to find the details, that's why have a proper naming convention in the project is necessary. For classes, you can find in which test class they are being used, by searching your code in any IDE of your choice. Hope that your fellow developers have not tried to cover multiple classes/riggers in single test class.

Comment: @Novarg Thanks for the reply. But if suppose ApexClass name contains "test" keyword then how can we differentiate??

Comment: @amitpatil use `TEST_` as a prefix. For example you can also prefix VF controllers with `VFContr_`, then your TC for this controller will have "double prefix": `TEST_VF_Contr_`

Comment: @Rahul Sharma I don't want to do a manual search. I want to do programmatically because I have extracted components using ANT and developed a java program to create excel sheet so by using the program I can search test class name.

Comment: @Amit, You can scan the body of classes to check if they have `@IsTest` annotation. Problem would arise when you have the annotation in comments, so you would need to build a smart filter which ignore comments.

Comment: Related [How to get a list of Test Classes in an org](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/122870/102)

Comment: @martin I thought there was, but I can't find it currently.

Comment: My suggestion is to add _TEST at the end of the class/trg name instead of prefixing it. This is because at some point of time, the number of classes you have in the org will explode and then it would be nice to have the TEST class right next to the original class.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely start using a naming convention where test classes stand out by looking at the name, but there are legitimate use cases for being able to programmatically query all test classes.

If you look at the developer console, they have their own _ui endpoint for performing such a query that you could use yourself, although it isn't officially supported:

```
$ curl -b 'sid=<session-id>' https://<instance>.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/test/ApexTestQueueServlet -d 'action=GET_TESTS' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

This will return normal classes that contain test methods.

---

If you want to use a standard api feature, another option would be to query the tooling api for code coverage, and all of the classes not present would be test classes:

```
$ curl -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <authorzation-token>' https://<instance>.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Coverage,ApexClassorTriggerId+FROM+ApexCodeCoverage
```

Normal classes with test methods will not be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to identify if an ApexClass contains test methods or not is to utilize the [SymbolTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm) via the Tooling API.

In particular, look at the [annotations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm#annotations_title) and/or [modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_symboltable.htm#modifiers_title) on the class and methods. They will tell you exactly if the `@IsTest` annotation is present or the `testMethod` modifier applied to a method.

Comment: @ Daniel Ballinger Thanks for your suggestion. For symbol Table which tooling object I have to use? Or tell me some sample query example.

Comment: @amitpatil You can use either the SOAP or REST version of the ToolingAPI. Usage is addressed in another question - [Symbol Table from Apex Class](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/116165/102)